# WooCommerce - PrettyPhoto appending URL with #prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, plugins

For some reason the PrettyPhoto script that WooCommerce is now using is adding #prettyPhoto to the end of URL's once it's been opened in that page.

[See here for an example](http://www.fullphattest.co.uk/emmm/shop/bebe-daisy-print-bunny-rattle/)

Also, when you close the lightbox down it takes 2 or 3 clicks of the back button to get back to where you were previously.

Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a … feature of this script, called *deeplinking*. It [should be fixed already](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2697), maybe you missed an update?

As you can see in that [commit](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/6d0cfda473974b7fd0697cd64c7d27c60f354438), you can disable it by editing `assets/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.init.js`. Add

```
deeplinking: false
```

… to all calls of `prettyPhoto({});`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise there was an update available!